# How to get current theme in grafana react panel?

Tags: reactjs, grafana

I'm developping a grafana react panel with @grafana/ui package.

I would like to style the panel specifically for dark and light themes.

So how do I get the current theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the theme mode is available from the config exported to the plugin.

Here is a sample code to get the current theme mode:

```js
import config from "grafana/app/core/config";

const isDarkMode = config.theme.isDark;
```

If you are using typescript, you can add `https://github.com/CorpGlory/types-grafana` as your dev dependency, which provides some useful hint. But be aware it is not up to date.

Comment: Since grafana 6, it's possible to use `import {config} from '@grafana/runtime'`

Comment: @Adelise can you pl show me the example on how you have achieved theme using @grafana/runtime

Comment: @Adelise if you can provide an example it would be really appreciated

Comment: @Adelise I tried the following from github code in grafana but it is not working.

import { loadPluginCss, config } from '@grafana/runtime';

    const theme = config.bootData.user.lightTheme ? 'light' : 'dark';
    console.log(theme);
    SystemJS.import(`${theme}!css`);

Comment: @Optimus @dimitar-petrov In fact, I didn't built a full theme. I just updated a component style (Ace editor or Plotly chart) using the current selected theme. First, I do the import : `import {config} from '@grafana/runtime';`. Then I use `let theme = config.theme.isDark?"tomorrow_night":"tomorrow";` to detect the theme and choose the right style for my component. Finally, I set the variable to my react component(React-Ace) : ` <AceEditor  theme={theme}  ...  />`.
So, you probably need to ask a new question for your specific need...

Answer (score 0):

1. Please install @grafana/runtime
2. import {config} from '@grafana/runtime';
3. let isDark = config.theme.isDark;